# Get Data Week Wise in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql

I have a Table with columns `ProductId`, `DateofPurchase`, `Quantity`.
I want a report in which week it belongs to.
Suppose if I give March Month I can get the quantity for the march month.

But I want as below if I give date as parameter.
Here `Quantity` available for March month on `23/03/2018 is 100`

```
Material Code   Week1   Week2   Week3   Week4

12475           -       -       -       100
```

The logic is 1-7 first week, 8-15 second week, 16-23 third week, 24-30 fourth week

Comment: please post queries to create the table and insert sample data. In addition provide the requested result according to the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

@Sasi, this can get you started. YOu will need to use CTE to build a template table that describes what happens yearly. Then using your table with inner join you can link it up and do a pivot to group the weeks.
Let me know if you need any tweaking.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE='20180101'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE='20180901'

DECLARE @Dates TABLE(
      Workdate DATE  Primary Key
)


DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ProductId INT, DateofPurchase DATE, Quantity INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl 
SELECT 12475, '20180623', 100

;WITH Dates AS(
      SELECT Workdate=@StartDate,WorkMonth=DATENAME(MONTH,@StartDate),WorkYear=YEAR(@StartDate), WorkWeek=datename(wk, @StartDate )
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CurrDate=DateAdd(WEEK,1,Workdate),WorkMonth=DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd(WEEK,1,Workdate)),YEAR(DateAdd(WEEK,1,Workdate)),datename(wk, DateAdd(WEEK,1,Workdate)) FROM Dates D WHERE Workdate<@EndDate ---AND (DATENAME(MONTH,D.Workdate))=(DATENAME(MONTH,D.Workdate))
)



SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        sal.ProductId,
            GroupWeek='Week'+
                CASE 
                    WHEN WorkWeek BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN '1' 
                    WHEN WorkWeek BETWEEN 8 AND 15 THEN '2' 
                    WHEN WorkWeek BETWEEN 16 AND 23 THEN '3' 
                    WHEN WorkWeek BETWEEN 24 AND 30 THEN '4' 
                    WHEN WorkWeek BETWEEN 31 AND 37 THEN '5' 
                    WHEN WorkWeek BETWEEN 38 AND 42 THEN '6' 
                END,
        Quantity
    FROM
        Dates D
         JOIN @tbl sal on
            sal.DateofPurchase between D.Workdate and DateAdd(DAY,6,Workdate)
    )T

    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Quantity) FOR GroupWeek IN (Week1,  Week2,  Week3,  Week4,  Week5,  Week6,  Week7,  Week8,  Week9,  Week10, Week11, Week12, Week13, Week14, Week15, Week16, Week17, Week18, Week19, Week20, Week21, Week22, Week23, Week24, Week25, Week26, Week27, Week28, Week29, Week30, Week31, Week32, Week33, Week34, Week35, Week36, Week37, Week38, Week39, Week40, Week41, Week42, Week43, Week44, Week45, Week46, Week47, Week48, Week49, Week50, Week51, Week52

         /*add as many as you need*/)
    )p

--ORDER BY
--1

option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: @sasi, could you please mark as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data :

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE(Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                        ProductName NVARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @Orders TABLE(ProductId INT,
                      DateofPurchase DATETIME,
                      Quantity BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @Products(Id,ProductName)
VALUES(1,N'Product1'),
      (2,N'Product2')

INSERT INTO @Orders( ProductId ,DateofPurchase ,Quantity)
VALUES  (1,'2018-01-01',130),
        (1,'2018-01-09',140),
        (1,'2018-01-16',150),
        (1,'2018-01-24',160),
        (2,'2018-01-01',30),
        (2,'2018-01-09',40),
        (2,'2018-01-16',50),
        (2,'2018-01-24',60)
```

Query :

```
SELECT P.Id,
       P.ProductName,
       Orders.MonthName,
       Orders.Week1,
       Orders.Week2,
       Orders.Week3,
       Orders.Week4
FROM @Products AS P
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  O.ProductId,
                        SUM((CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,O.DateofPurchase) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN O.Quantity ELSE 0 END)) AS Week1,
                        SUM((CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,O.DateofPurchase) BETWEEN 8 AND 15 THEN O.Quantity ELSE 0 END)) AS Week2,
                        SUM((CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,O.DateofPurchase) BETWEEN 16 AND 23 THEN O.Quantity ELSE 0 END)) AS Week3,
                        SUM((CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,O.DateofPurchase) >= 24 THEN O.Quantity ELSE 0 END)) AS Week4,
                        DATENAME(MONTH,O.DateofPurchase) AS MonthName
                FROM @Orders AS O
                GROUP BY O.ProductId,DATENAME(MONTH,O.DateofPurchase)) AS Orders ON P.Id = Orders.ProductId
```

Result :

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Id | ProductName   | MonthNumber   | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | Week4 |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1  | Product1      | January       | 130   | 140   | 150   | 160   |
|    2  | Product2      | January       | 30    | 40    | 50    | 60    |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me as how i expected.